# How can I add image to PFTableViewCell Swift 2 Xcode 7

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform, tableview

I am trying to display some text and images in a PFTableViewCell using Parse and Swift 2. I am able to fully display the text inside the cells but when I add the code for the images to display and run the application, it gives me the following error: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
Here is the code I'm using in:

```
     var textArray = [String]()
var imageArray = [UIImage]()



@IBOutlet weak var tableView2: UITableView!




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let shopList = PFQuery(className:"Shops")
    let runkey = shopList.orderByAscending("shopName")

    runkey.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in


        if error == nil {
            if let objects = objects as [PFObject]! {
                for object in objects {
                    let loadTxt = object.objectForKey("shopName") as! String
                    let loadImg = object.objectForKey("shopImages") as! UIImage

                    self.imageArray.append(loadImg)
                    self.textArray.append(loadTxt)


                    print(self.textArray)


                }
            }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.labelShopName?.text = textArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.shopImages?.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]




    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would need to know on which line the error occurred. My guess is that the data you are trying to pull = nil for some reason. To check if anything is being returned, comment out the line where the code is failing and do "print()". If nil is returned, you have to try something else because the image is not being downloaded.